# Azure Devops Server on AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: amazon-rds, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm planning to migrate our on-prem Azure Devops Server to Amazon AWS and would like to use SQL Server via AWS RDS as it's underlying database. I know that SQL Server running in AWS RDS has some limitations compared to a "normal" SQL Server running on a Windows Server VM. So I would like to know whether that difference would affect my Azure Devops Server installation in AWS in any way.

So, does Azure DevOps Server support running on an AWS RDS MS SQL Server database?

I looked everywhere for an answer, but did not manage to find an exact one.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the server? Are you referring to Azure Pipelines, specifically, for e.g. continuous integration? If you can tell us more about the use case, we can provide more specific guidance.

Comment: Hi, I'm planning to migrate our on-prem Azure Devops Server to Amazon AWS and would like to use SQL Server via AWS RDS as it's underlying database. I know that SQL Server running in AWS RDS has some limitations compared to a "normal" SQL Server running on a Windows Server VM. So I would like to know whether that difference would affect my Azure Devops Server installation in AWS in any way. Thanks!

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. I don't have much knowledge here, but hopefully others in the community will have some insight to share.

Comment: Added this further explanation to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

**bacpac method**

You can achieve this by using the native backup and restore method, we can either use .bak (native backups) or .bacpac (backup package).